# Applying gaussian mask in cuda kernel using shared memory

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, convolution

I am trying to complete the homework for the udacity "intro to parallel programming" course and I am stuck at the second assignment which is basically applying a gaussian blur mask to an image using CUDA.
I want to do this efficiently by exploiting shared memory.
My idea for solving the "pixels at the border problem" was to launch more threads than the actual number of pixels in a block: for example, if I am dividing the input image in blocks of active pixels of 16x16 in size, and I have a mask of 9x9 in size then my actual block dimension will be (for both x and y): 16+2*(9/2) = 24. In this way I am launching 24 threads in a block so that the "outer" threads will just be used to load pixel from the input img to the shared mem, while the "inner" threads correspond to active pixels that actually perform computation (in addition of also caching in shared mem).

For some reason it doesn't work. As you can see from the attached code, I am able to cache pixels into shared memory, but something gets terribly wrong during the computation, and I am attaching an image of the poor results that I'm getting.

```
               __global__ void gaussian_blur(const unsigned char* const inputChannel,
               unsigned char* const outputChannel,
               int numRows, int numCols,
               const float* const filter, const int filterWidth)
               {

int filter_radius = (int)(filterWidth / 2); //getting the filter "radius"

int x = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
int y = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y+threadIdx.y;

if(x>=(numCols+filter_radius) || y>=(numRows+filter_radius)) 
    return;

int px = x-filter_radius;
int py = y-filter_radius;

//clamping

if(px<0) px = 0;
if(py<0) py = 0;
//if(px>=numCols) px = numCols-1;
// if(py>=numRows) py = numRows-1;

 __shared__ unsigned char tile[(16+8)*(16+8)]; //16 active pixels + 2*filter_radius

 tile[threadIdx.y*24+threadIdx.x] = inputChannel[py*numCols+px];

 __syncthreads();  

//Here everything is working fine: if I do
//  outputChannel[py*numCols+px] = tile[threadIdx.y*24+threadIdx.x]; 
//then I am able to see the perfect reconstruction of the input image.

//caching the filter
__shared__ float t_filter[81]; //9x9 conv mask

if(threadIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.y==0)
{
    for(int i=0; i<81; i++)
        t_filter[i] = filter[i];
}

__syncthreads();


//I am checking the threadIdx of the threads and I am performing the mask computation
//only to those threads that are pointing to active pixels:
//i.e. all the threads whose id is greater or equal to the filter radius,
//but smaller than the whole block of active pixels will perform the computation.
//filter_radius = filterWidth/2 = 9/2 = 4
//blockDim.x or y = 16 + filterWidth*2 = 16+8 = 24
//active pixel index limit = filter_radius+16 = 4+16 = 20
//is that correct?


if(  
     threadIdx.y>=filter_radius && threadIdx.x>=filter_radius &&
     threadIdx.x < 20 && threadIdx.y < 20
  )
{ 

    float value = 0.0;

    for(int i=-filter_radius; i<=filter_radius; i++)
        for(int j=-filter_radius; j<=filter_radius; j++)
        {
            int fx = i+filter_radius;
            int fy = j+filter_radius;

            int ty = threadIdx.y+i;
            int tx = threadIdx.x+j;

            value += ((float)tile[ty*24+tx])*t_filter[fy*filterWidth+fx];
        }
    outputChannel[py*numCols+px] = (unsigned char) value; 
}
```

Output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMu5M.png

EDIT: adding kernel calls:

```
int filter_radius = (int) (filterWidth / 2);
    blockSize.x = 16 + 2*filter_radius;
    blockSize.y = 16 + 2*filter_radius;
    gridSize.x = numCols/16+1;
    gridSize.y = numRows/16+1;

    printf("\n grx %d gry %d \n", blockSize.x, blockSize.y );

    gaussian_blur<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_red, d_redBlurred, numRows,numCols, d_filter, filterWidth);
    gaussian_blur<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_green, d_greenBlurred, numRows,numCols, d_filter, filterWidth);
    gaussian_blur<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_blue, d_blueBlurred, numRows,numCols, d_filter, filterWidth);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

     blockSize.x = 32;   gridSize.x = numCols/32+1;
     blockSize.y = 32;   gridSize.y = numRows/32+1;

  // Now we recombine your results. We take care of launching this kernel for you.
  //
  // NOTE: This kernel launch depends on the gridSize and blockSize variables,
  // which you must set yourself.
  recombineChannels<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_redBlurred,
                                             d_greenBlurred,
                                             d_blueBlurred,
                                             d_outputImageRGBA,
                                             numRows,
                                             numCols);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
```

EDIT bis:

all the other necessary code in order to compile and run can be found here: 
https://github.com/udacity/cs344/tree/master/Problem%20Sets/Problem%20Set%202
and the above kernel should be coded in the student_func.cu file.

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example(MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."  A CUDA kernel by itself is not a MCVE. Preferably, your MCVE should be standalone, and should not require OpenCV or other frameworks, or separate data files.

Comment: Well sorry then, as I browsed some CUDA questions here and none of them are displaying the whole thing. Some of them may display the kernel call itself, but I am pretty sure when dealing with images that none of them provide their own functions for reading and outputting image files, so to avoid using OpenCV or other frameworks. I am adding the kernel calls and posting a link to the other files needed for compiling. I think it should be sufficient. As far as what this code is supposed to do, I think it is very well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your implementation each block will never compute the blur for the boundary (within one filter radius of the edge) pixels. This means that you want your blocks to overlap so that the boundaries are covered. If you look at the domain of the `x` index for each block

```
int x = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
```

given your specific kernel execution above we would have

```
blockIdx.x = 0: x = [0,23]
blockIdx.x = 1: x = [24,46]
... etc
```

As you can see each block will consider a unique part of your image, but you have told each block not to compute on the boundary. This means the boundary of each block is omitted from your computation (hence the black grid in your image).

You need to calculate your indices with something like

```
int x = (blockDim.x-2*filter_radius)*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
```

so that the blocks overlap. Now our the domain of our `x` index will look like

```
blockIdx.x = 0: x = [0,23]
blockIdx.x = 1: x = [16,39]
... etc
```